# ofxCvGrayscaleImage from ofTexture

Tags: c++, openframeworks

Im using `ofxPS3EyeGrabber` to get two cameras working simultaniously. I already have both images, but now i want to make blob detention on them using `ofxOpenCv`.
Now i need to get  an `ofxCvGrayscaleImage`  from an `ofTexture`. Here is what i have:

```
 if (videoGrabbers[i]->isFrameNew())
        {
            videoTextures[i].loadData(videoGrabbers[i]->getPixelsRef());
        }
```

What i need is something like this:

```
grayImg.setFromPixels(videoTextures[i]->getPixelsRef());
```

But theres no `getPixelsRef()` in ofTexture.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `getPixelRef()` on the grabber instead? ofTexture doesn't have a getPixelsRef since it would be very ineffective. When you use loadData, the data is being moved from the cpu to the gpu, so getting pixels back on cpu would be a waste of moving pixels. Thats why you want to do it on the videograbber instead.